# Selenium HtmlUnitDriver Angular2

Tags: java, angular, selenium

I try to write a selenium test  With HtmlUnitDriver it is:

```
HtmlUnitDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();         
//driver.setJavascriptEnabled(true);            
driver.get(localhostURLAPI);            
System.out.println("source of the page now is " + driver.getPageSource());
```

but in the result I have juste the HTML of index.html **with an empty**

any help is welcome

Comment: google little bit how to launch selenium HtmlUnitDriver with enabled javascript. By default HtmlUnitDriver did not execute your scripts.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the line:

From :

```
HtmlUnitDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
```

To :

```
WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
```

Comment: I tested that but stel have the same thing; 

the probleme is I can not load the HTML code under <app-root> , so i can't get element by id for exemple, this is my result :

<html lang="en"> <head> <meta charset="utf-8"/> <title> API title </title> <base href="/"/> <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/> <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico"/> <body> <app-root/> </body> </html>